# Write two for instructions as a stream

Tags: java, stream

I have two lists of `Pearson` (variables: `FirstName`, `LastName`, `AllFirstName`). One of them contains duplicates (if a pearson has two first names then in that list will  have two entries for each name but the lastname will be the same) and one of them has only unique values (listWithUniquePearsons). The second list will be created by itereting over the first list and putting all the first name in a list of objects. I wrote this with two `for`. Is there any way to write it as a `stream`?

```
for (Pearson prs : listWithUniquePearsons) {
    List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Pearson tempPerson : allPearsons) {
        if (prs.getLastName().equals(tempPerson.getLastName())) {
            firstNames.add(tempPerson.firstNames());
        }
    }

    if (firstNames.size()>1) {
        prs.setAllFirstNames(firstNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: `AllFirstName` is a List of Strings?

Comment: can you show us your model please?

Comment: Yes, it is a list of String.

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<String> firstNames = listWithUniquePearsons
        .stream()
        .map(prs -> allPearsons.stream()
                               .filter(tempPerson -> prs.getLastName().equals(tempPerson.getLastName()))
                               .map(Person::getFirstName)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This code is broken and does not compile, the first `map` operation is not completed.  Did you mean to use `flatMap`?

Answer (score 0):

You should build a map with a key `lastName` and values `List<FirstName>` and then remap its entries back to Pearson class setting `allFirstNames`.  This can be done using Java 8 streams and collectors.

Let's assume that class `Pearson` is implemented as follows:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Pearson {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<String> allFirstNames;
        
    public Pearson(String first, String last) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
    }
        
    public Pearson(List<String> allFirst, String last) {
        this.allFirstNames = allFirst;
        this.lastName = last;
    }
        
    public String getFirstName() {return firstName; }
    public String getLastName() {return lastName; }
    public List<String> getAllFirstNames() {return allFirstNames; }
}
```

Test code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pearson> duplicates = Arrays.asList(
            new Pearson("John", "Doe"),
            new Pearson("William", "Doe"),
            new Pearson("Edgar", "Poe"),
            new Pearson("Allan", "Poe"),
            new Pearson("Don", "King")
        );
        List<Pearson> uniques = duplicates.stream()
                                          // map LastName -> List<FirstName>
                                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                              Pearson::getLastName,
                                              LinkedHashMap::new, // keep order of entries
                                              Collectors.mapping(
                                                  Pearson::getFirstName,
                                                  Collectors.toList())
                                          )).entrySet()
                                          .stream()
                                          .map(e -> new Pearson(e.getValue(), e.getKey()))
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        uniques.forEach(u -> 
            System.out.println(
                String.join(" ", u.getAllFirstNames()) 
                + " " + u.getLastName()
        ));   
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
John William Doe
Edgar Allan Poe
Don King
```